# Ajax CORS request with redirect fails on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, cors

I have a url that is being redirect to another domain, by the server.
My very simple test code looks like that:

```js
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",  
        url:"{MYURL}",  
        success:function(d){alert('response');}  
 })
```

and you can view the running script in [this link](http://digitalcontent.tv/dev/ad_serv.html)

I get the "response" alert on all browsers and platforms except on iOS (iPhone/iPad)
on iOs I get "Cannot make any requests from null".
Any help will be appreciated.

Ofer

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a bug in iOS
In iOS 10.1.1 it is working